# Hovering over image hides the "register here" link

Tags: html, css, mousehover

When I mouse hover the image my REGISTER HERE link is getting hidden.

I don't want hover effect on it but i want that link on the same position below the image.

```css
.image {
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:10px;
}
.overlay {
 display:none;
}
.image:hover .overlay {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 border:10px solid red;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:inline-block;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 padding:12px;
 font-size:20px;
}
img {
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="course">
<div class="image">
 <figure>
 <img  src="http://placekitten.com/250/200"  width="100%" height:"100%">   
 <div class="overlay">Click on the Register Here to know about the:-
  <ul>
   <li>Oracle</li>
   <li>Automated Testing</li>
  </ul> 
 </div>
<figcaption><a href="register.html">Register Here</a></figcaption>
 </figure>
  </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: shakira, always post your code here. If you can't be bothered to make your question as good as it can be then why should people be bothered to answer it?

Comment: i am very sorry i am new over here so next time i will keep these in mind

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't next links. And if you don't want the register link to be part of the hover, then don't put it within the div that you're attaching the hover to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below style -

```
.course{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

---

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
.overlay {
  display: none;
}
.image a:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border: 10px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.course{
position: relative;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="course">
  <div class="image">
<figure>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/200" width="100%" height: "100%">
  <div class="overlay">Click on the Register Here to know about the:-
    <ul>
      <li>Oracle</li>
      <li>Automated Testing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <figcaption><a href="register.html">Register Here</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you some much for your it helped me but i have one last query when i hover the REGISTERED HERE link the image hover effect should not show. It should show only when i hover over image not on the link.

Comment: changed `.image:hover .overlay` to `.image a:hover .overlay`.. please check the above code again.